# Charges against NASA Administrator James Beggs?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, history

James M Beggs was NASA administrator from 1981 to 1985.   He was accused of and later completely exonerated of contract fraud. What were the details of the charges and why were they later completely dropped?

Some background:
http://articles.latimes.com/1988-07-07/news/mn-8324_1_profound-apology

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad @ChallengerTruth, you are asking 3 questions at once, two of which are opinion based.

Comment: Your article suggests the indictment was related to weapons contracts when he was working at General Dynamics Corp. How is this related to space exploration? I think this will be considered off-topic if the "too broad" hold is released, but let's see what happens.

Comment: I have removed the third question. Maybe it is now compact enough to reopen.

Comment: The contract itself had nothing to do with Space Exploration, but the fact that a NASA administrator was accused by the Department of Defense of contract fraud, forced to resign and then exonerated by the courts played a role in the shuttle program.   For example, Administrator Beggs was on record as being opposed to the Air Force having a separate launch system.    His successor, William Graham, a former Air Force project officer, was on record as supporting an Air Force launch Vehicle separate from the STS.   Had Administrator Beggs stayed in office, perhaps their would have been no Titan IV

Comment: This prosecution appeared to be a witch hunt from the very beginning, within a couple days of the filing of charges, the SECDEF, Cap Weinberger showed a very personal interest in the case.   He appeared on CBS Morning news to suggest, even before a trial, that the defendants should be sentenced to long criminal terms.   "But we, unfortunately, don't administer the sentence"    http://www.upi.com/Archives/1985/12/06/Weinberger-favors-jail-for-guilty-contractors/8863502693200/    It seems very clear that the SECDEF was personally involved in this prosecution.